# I can't change the state in callback axios (I used useEffect, useState, axios)

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

```
function User() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const user-token = window.localStorage.getItem('user-token');
        const getUser = async () => {
        if (user-token !== null) {
            const user = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/index/info')

            setUser(user.data.info)
            console.log(user.data.info) // server return result is what I expected: {name: "hanh", age: 20}
            console.log(user) // but this is not change, it still {} 
        }

        getUser()
    }, []
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `setUser` runs asynchronously, and `console.log(user)` gets executed before the state is updated.

You can use `useEffect` to check if state is updated or not.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(user)
}, [user])
```

the effect will be executed every time user changes

If you want to have a callback each and every time state changes then you can write customHook as below

```
function useStateWithCallBack(initlaValue, callBack) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initlaValue);
  useEffect(() => callBack(state), [state]);
  return [state, setState];
}
```

You can find a working example for such `customHook` in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/usestatewithcallback-3vwjf) sandbox:

Comment: Tks for answer, now, I know and remember synchronous and asynchronous, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

remove these

console.log(user.data.info)
console.log(user)

add this

```js
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(user) 
},[user])
```

```js
function User() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const user-token = window.localStorage.getItem('user-token');
        const getUser = async () => {
        if (user-token !== null) {
            const user = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/index/info')

            setUser(user.data.info)
        }


    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(user) 
    },[user]);

}
```

Comment: We see what you changed, but how does that resolve the question asked?

Comment: Thank you Dean for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
function User() {
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const userToken = window.localStorage.getItem('userToken');
        const getUser = async () => {
        if (userToken !== null) {
            const user = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/index/info')

            setUserState(user.data.info)
            console.log(user.data.info) // server return result is what I expected: {name: "hanh", age: 20}
        }
        getUser()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(userState)
    },[userState])
}
```

or like below if somewhere else use the userInfo

```
function User() {
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState({})
    const userRef = useRef({})

    useEffect(() => {
        const userToken = window.localStorage.getItem('userToken');
        const getUser = async () => {
        if (userToken !== null) {
            const user = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/index/info')

            setUserState(user.data.info)
            userRef.current = user.data.info // somewhere else can acquire userinfo by userRef.current
            console.log(userRef.current)
        }
        getUser()
    }, [])
}
```

Comment: What did you change, and how does that resolve the question asked?

Comment: i mean when you need mock the callback effect like the previous `this.setState(state, callback)` in hooks, you may always need other `useEffect` and put the `state` as its deps.

Comment: and if you want the change of state be acquired immediately, you may need store the changed state to a ref (can be acquired without reredering).